# SPSS: automatic counting of follow-up moments in a longitudinal long format database

Tags: data-structures, data-cleaning, spss, longitudinal, long-format-data

I would like to structure my long format SPSS file so I can clean it and get a better overview. However, I run into some problems.

How can i create a new veriable counting the complation moments/waves/follow-up moments. I only have a completion data avaible in my dataset. Please open my image for a more explanation.

Preferably a numbering that continues counting if a year is missing.

[image]

Comment: in the above example, shouldn't the numbers be 1=2017, 4=2020, 5=2021 ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want the new variable to be an index of the year of involvement for each patient, as opposed to an index of data row per patient. To do this we can calculate for each entry the difference in years between the entry and the first entry of that patient:
(this assumes your dates are in date format)

```
compute year=xdate.year(OpenInvulMomenten).
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables /break=PatientIdPseudo /firstYear=min(year).
compute newvar=1+year-firstYear.
exe.
```